# Casimir effect and lambshift, uncontroversial evidence of the zero point field? (SED)

Tags: quantum-field-theory, atomic-physics, quantum-electrodynamics, casimir-effect

> "By far the most accepted evidence of the reality of the zpf is the Casimir effect, that is, the force between two parallel neutral metallic plates resulting from the modification of the field by the bound." - Cetto et al, The Emerging Quantum (2015).

> "As mentioned..., today it is well accepted that the fluctuations of the electromagnetic vacuum are responsible for important observable physical phenomena. Perhaps their best known manifestations, within the atomic domain, are the Lamb shift of energy levels...  and their contribution to the spontaneous transitions of the excited states to the ground state" - Cetto et al, The Emerging Quantum (2015).

To recall, the governing equation of stochastic electrodynamics is
$$\ddot {{\bf x}}={\bf f}({\bf x})+m\tau \dddot {\bf x}+e{\bf E}({\bf x},t)+\frac{e}{c} {\bf v}\times {\bf B}({\bf x},t),$$
where ${\bf f}$ is an external force, the second term $m\tau \dddot {\bf x}$ describes the self-radiation force, and importantly the last two terms describe the Lorentz force due to the fluctuating zero point field (zpf) referenced in the quote. From the equation the Schrodringer equation can be derived after many approximations as shown in the book emerging quantum, I am not sure if the theory can be extended to relativistic regimes.

Question: As is evident from the quote, the Casimir effect and lamb shift has been taken to validate SED in some sort of mechanistic sense, and even in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_electrodynamics) the SED based explanation of Casimir effect is considered uncontroversial. However, there have been papers such as [1](https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.04143) (and others) arguing that the Casimir effect is just the van der Waals force, and moreover the standard textbook calculation is carried out hastly. In the light of these developments, how valid are the quotes by Cetto et al. (2015) in Emerging Quantum?